# How to use .hide on a Qt LineEdit, still take input?

Tags: c++, qt, input, qt4, hidden

I have a QLineEdit which I would like to hide from the user but still take in input form somewhere. I am creating a typing tutor and I want to take input in a hidden manner in order to provide a more dynamic form of feedback.

Any other suggestions as to best accomplish would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Widgets have the focus only if they're visible. Maybe you could override the `keyPress` protected function to simulate what you want, on the widget that will be displayed to user.

Comment: In this case, you'll want to implement and use the QWidget::keyPressEvent and keyReleaseEvent virtual functions instead of an input control line QLineEdit.

Answer (score 3):

You can not do it. When `QLineEdit` is hidden, there is no focus on it, and you can not grab events.

If you persist on using `QLineEdit` there's an option to turn off displaying  text.[`QLineEdit::NoEcho`](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qlineedit.html#EchoMode-enum).

```
lineEdit->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::NoEcho);
```

This will show the edit box, but it doesn't show any text.

Otherwise, you should write a slot to grab window `keyPressed` signals, and handle everything yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For other people who try to do such a thing, a workaround is simply to implement a QLineEdit visible, but with a MinimumSize = MaximumSize = 0x0 :)

Comment: If you want your QLineEdit to be invisible, but to capture keyboard events, you can create a QLineEdit with size 0 x 0, and still set it "visible", with the focus on it, in order to grab the keyboard events.